# Firestore Query Documents With Similar Array (Node.js/Admin SDK)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Imagine you have this array

```
[10.3, 14, 12.4, 3.5]
```

and in your DB you also have two documents with those arrays:

```
First document -> [10, 13.1, 0, -10]
Second document -> [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now imagine that you have +1000000 documents with the same two arrays (alterning between each one)... Is there any way to get all documents that have similar values as your current array?

I mean, something like this:

```
   ...
   .where("array", "isSimilar", yourArray)
   .get()
```

So that I get all documents which have the array:

```
[10, 13.1, 0, -10]
```

Or the only way is to download every single document, something that can be really slow, and then iterate and search the most similar? I think this can be really interesting when talking about "similar points positions", "weeks in which a user has lost similar weight", ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, firestore doesn't support that kind of query. So I suggest that you update your structure to include a String field for array comparison. So each document would look like this:

```js
{
   array: [12, 11, 8, 9],
   arrayStr: "12,11,8,9",
   ...
}
```

You can achieve this structure simply by calling `doc.array.join(",")` on all existing documents and saving the value to the document.

Then, it'll be possible to make the comparisons with firestore query, like so:

```js
const arrToCompare = [12, 11, 8, 9];
const snapshot = await firestore().collection(collection).where("arrayStr", "==", arrToCompare.join(",")).get();
...
```

UPDATE: To compare by similarity instead of equality, a possible approach is to apply your "similarity" logic to the `arrayStr` field during creation. For example, if you want differences less than 0.5 to be tolerated, you could use `Math.round()` on the array elements before saving as string. Like so:

```js
const array = [12.2, 10.7, 8.111, 9.0];
const arrayStr = array.map(num => Math.round(num)).join(","); //"12,11,8,9"
```

Then you'll query like this:

```js
const arrToCompare = [12, 11, 8, 9];
const snapshot = await firestore().collection(collection).where("arrayStr", "==", arrToCompare.map(num => Math.round(num)).join(",")).get();
// Results would include arrays like [12.2, 10.7, 8.111, 9.0]
...
```

Of course, you could vary the argument passed to `Math.round()` in order to increase or reduce the level of tolerance for the comparisons

Comment: This seems really useful. Thank you. But, would it be possible to compare the items? I mean, I want similar arrays (for example, each numeric item can have an epsilon of margin)

Comment: Do you mean that small differences should be tolerated by the comparison? Hence, comparing on similarity instead of equality? Like "2.118" matching "2.1"?

Comment: Yeah, exactly this.

Comment: I also need similarity, not equality.